# SNMP management information base

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, mib, snmp4j

I have a question that annoys me about SNMP protocol and more especially the MIB database. Well, I will try to put you in the context of the work:
I will develop an application that allows me to query a SNMP agent to retrieve information, but the question is: What type of OID should I send?

I will begin to query virtual machines to test the application. The OS of the VMs is ubuntu.

What bothers me is that I do not understand the MIB table.

- Is the MIB table propitious to each constructor or operating system?
- If it is linked to an SE where I can find the ubuntu MIB files?

Is it OK to start a test on VMs, and then I generalize the case for routers and switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A management information base (MIB) is a database used for managing the entities in a communication network. Most often associated with the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP), the term is also used more generically in contexts such as in OSI/ISO Network management model. While intended to refer to the complete collection of management information available on an entity, it is often used to refer to a particular subset, more correctly referred to as MIB-module.
There are a large number of MIBs defined by both standards organizations like the IETF, private enterprises and other entities.

It's ok to start your test on VMs.

Comment: You Can use [Unetlab](http://www.unetlab.com/), powerfull and feature rich network simulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I want to query a virtual machine under ubuntu what shall I do?
What kind of information can I have?
Where can I get the ubuntu MIB table?

Comment: I hope this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222823/how-to-get-or-configure-ip-mib-in-ubuntu-12-04) can help you.